# Customize the POST request in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, post, typescript

I'm creating a POST request, but I also need to specify the "type link relation".So the body should look like this:

```
  {
                "_links":{
                    "type":{
                        "href":"http://example.co.uk/rest/type/node/article"
                    }
                },
                "title":[{"value": "Blog title"}],
                "body":[{"value": "Body content"}]
            }
```

So far I'm getting the title and the body from user input (a form), but I don't know how to add this new object to my request.

This is my service:

```
  createBlog(blog: Blog): Observable<any>{
          let url = this.API_URL + "entity/node";
          return this.http.post(url, blog,  {headers:this.headers}).map(res => res.json()).catch(err => {

            return Observable.throw(err);
          });
        }
```

With this I get a bad request

```
400 Bad bequest
Response {_body: "{"error":"The type link relation must be specified."}", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers…}
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably expand the Blog object like this:

```
createBlog(blog: Blog): Observable<any>{
  blog._links = {type : { href: 'http://example.co.uk/rest/type/node/article' } };
  ....
}
```

And for that to work you will need to change the Blog model to contain a _link property of the type Object.

```
export class Blog {
    _links: Object;
    title: Array<Object>;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like is working but now I get 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: That's probably an endpoint problem and maybe because of some other parameters in the request. Check which parameters you have to submit to the endpoint.

Comment: Is a bit strange as none of the parameters is required at the endpoint and I don't have this problem using Postman. But nevertheless, you answered my initial question so I will accept it.
Thank you for help Victor.